# Does Silent Post work in Payflow Pro Recurring Payments?

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

Does Silent Post work in Payflow Pro Recurring Payments too? How will I know if the payment is successful or not for each recurring Payment Transaction.

Answer (score 0):

For Payflow recurring billing Silent Post does **not** work.
Silent post is called only when hosted page is invoked.

For manually knowing the status of each recurring payment transaction you can use `Inquiry` API call.

If you are using PayPal API, you can use IPN.

Comment: I know Silent Url, but Is this valid with recurring payments using payflow pro api? thanks

Comment: yes, it should be valid as far as i know.
Similaryl, who IPN works for CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.

Comment: thanks anyway, but it not working with Payflow api..it not supporting ipn.

Comment: @Uzodocs Yes, recurring billing does not silent post
silent post is only called when hosted page is invoked.